# Remove "Are You Sure" dialogue when leaving editor

Tags: tinymce

Anyone know of a nice way to disable that pop-up dialogue when exiting the post-editor?
It says "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved."

Nice feature, but annoying in certain blogs where I have to edit a ton of posts

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705671/how-to-disable-tinymce-confirm-dialog). Add the following to your `functions.php`

```
<?php
function wpse35898_admin_head() {  
    ?> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        window.onbeforeunload = function() {};
    </script> 
    <?php 
} 
add_action( 'admin_head' , 'wpse35898_admin_head' ); 
?>
```

Comment: I tried your code. I can see where it is inserting the script into the head but still no joy. Any thoughts? have you seen this in action?

Comment: I haven't tried, but it should overwrite the `window.onbeforeunload` event so nothing happens. Can you track that the function is called with firebug?

Comment: This would work, except that the `window.onbeforeunload` method is redefined every time the tinymce box gets out of sync with the autosaved post. If you want to prevent it from occuring again, I think you should be able to just change the text of the confirmation message to **true**. ie. `autosaveL10n.saveAlert = true`.

Answer (score 0):

```
tinyMCE.init({
     .................................

     .................................

    autosave_ask_before_unload:false
  })
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705671/how-to-disable-tinymce-confirm-dialog) page

you must to add         "autosave_ask_before_unload: false" in init of tinymce(as bottom code):

```
tinymce.init({
        mode: 'textareas',
        menubar: false,
        statusbar: false,
        language: 'sv_SE',
        autosave_ask_before_unload: false,
        ...
```

and you must be add bottom code in your page:

```
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = function() {};
</script>
```

Comment: Do you really need both? I'm not that comfortable just removing all onbeforeunload handlers, which may not just be TinyMCE.

Comment: In my case both of them needed.